# pthread on MinGW 32 with eclipse 64 bit

Tags: c++, mingw, pthreads-win32

I have MinGW32 and building a small piece of code using pthread on eclipse. The code compiles and links successfully, but terminates on running it with a non zero exit value. There are no warnings around this.However, on debugging it,it works fine. Pls advice.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

pthread_mutex_t counter_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void* increment(void* counter)
{

    cout << "increment" << endl;
    int* pcounter = (int*)counter;
    for(int i =0; i < 30000; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Inside for loop" << endl;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&counter_mutex);
        ++(*pcounter);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&counter_mutex);
    }
}

int main()

{

    pthread_t arr[5];

    int counter =0;
    for(int i=0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Creating thread: " << i << endl;
        int rc = pthread_create(&arr[i], NULL, increment, (void*)&counter);
        if(rc != 0)
        {
            cout << "Error creating thread: " << rc << endl;
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i < 5 ; ++i)
    {
        pthread_join(arr[i], NULL);
    }

    cout << "result: " << counter << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Retagged. I'm pretty sure your problems aren't caused by using eclipse as IDE.

Comment: Your `increment` doesn't return value.

Comment: yes, that comes as a warning. But is not the reason here.

Comment: @Neha _But is not the reason here._ Sure? Did you fix it?

Comment: Yes, I did but it didn't resolve the problem.